# Composer skipping post update commands in Symfony 4.4

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I'm upgrading a Symfony project from 3.4 to 4.4.8. The Sensio Distribution Bundle is replaced by Flex, so I updated the scripts section of composer.json this way :

```
"scripts": {
    "auto-scripts": {
        "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
        "assets:install %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd"
    },
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "@auto-scripts"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "@auto-scripts"
    ]
},
```

When I run a composer update, composer warns that the commands were skipped :

> Skipping "cache:clear" (needs symfony/console to run).
>
> Skipping "assets:install public" (needs symfony/console to run).

Looking at composer.lock, symfony/console isn't installed, as symfony/symfony replaces symfony/console. Running a composer req cli doesn't help. I have no problem running symfony console commands (internal and custom) from the shell

I'm running latest stable version of composer (1.10.6). Is there somehting that I am missing ?

Comment: Upgrading major versions of Symfony can be tricky as some of the composer philosophy typically changes.  I would suggest creating a new 4.4 project, adding in your third party bundles and use the resulting composer.json file as a reference.

Comment: I'll probably resort to this as last option, as the project is pretty large, but I'm tempted nevertheless to have a full "symfony 4.4 native" architecture

Comment: Just to be clear, I am not explicitly recommending refactoring the entire project.  Just generating a new composer.json file.

Answer (score 0):

That error message shows you that you are missing the "symfony/console" library.

Add it with:

```
composer require symfony/console
```

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, this command is equivalent to "composer req cli", but either way, I tried both without success. symfony/console appears in my composer.json, but not in my composer.lock

Comment: Then i would suggest to delete the lock file and vendor folder if possible. Only disadvantage is that the packages will be updated if you did not specify the versions explicitly. But could be a way to make sure that everything is installed correctly. It might be necessary to delete the symfony.lock too.